# Exposing Snowflake Table Data as a REST API

Tags: python, api, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to expose snowflake table data as an API. 
But snowflake doesn't provide REST API to achieve this.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to implement something yourself.  A common approach an application that RESTfully listens for queries over HTTP, uses the Snowflake JDBC driver to retrieve the data, then encodes it into JSON and responds.  Here is a generic example: https://github.com/hellofiremind/jdbc-sql-rest

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the previous answer, you will have to connect snowflake using ODBC and implement APIs using a web framework.

There is also a new project Dozer that can instantly publish Snowflake as APIs.
https://github.com/getdozer/dozer

Disclaimer: I am one of the main contributors of Dozer.